# How can I avoid explicit recursion in this case?

Tags: haskell, recursion, type-inference, recursion-schemes, foldable

I wound up with this skeleton:

```
f :: (Monad m) => b -> m ()
f x = traverse_ (f . g x) =<< h x -- how avoid explicit recursion?
g :: b -> a -> b
-- h :: (Foldable t) => b -> m (t a) -- why "Could not deduce (Foldable t0) arising from a use of ‘traverse_’"
h :: b -> m [a]
```

How can I avoid the explicit recursion in `f`?

Bonus: When I try to generalize `h` from `[]` to `Foldable`, `f` does not type check (`Could not deduce (Foldable t0) arising from a use of ‘traverse_’`) -- what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Here's the real code.  The `Right` side is for recursing down directories of security camera footage whose names are integers.  `Left` is the base case to process leaves whose names are not integers.

```
a <|||> b = left a . right b

doDir (Right d) = traverse_ (doDir . doInt) =<< listDirectory d 
  where doInt s = ((<|||>) <$> (,) <*> const) (d </> s) $ (TR.readEither :: String -> Either String Int) s
```

`f = doDir` and `g ~ doInt` but got refactored a little.  `h = listDirectory`.  to answer the bonus, i was just being silly and wasn't seeing that i had to combine all the definitions to bind the types together:

```
f :: (Monad m, Foldable t) => (b -> a -> b) -> (b -> m (t a)) -> b -> m ()
f g h x = traverse_ (f g h . g x) =<< h x
```

Comment: Regarding your bonus question, if both the required and the provided type are polymorphic variables with some constraints then a concrete type must be chosen to be able to know which instance should be used. GHC doesn't want to make this choice for you because it changes the behavior of your program. You must manually disambiguate using a type signature or with `TypeApplications`.

Comment: `Foldable` doesn't include any methods with the container in positive position. So `h` cannot be implemented with that type, or even with any other type with fixed `b`, `m`, `a` but polymorphic `t`. So I don't see that this is a big problem. Show us what your *actual* `h` is and its type; then we can help you with your real program.

Comment: thanks guys, i updated with the real code and i'll look up positive position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind leaking a bit of memory building a `Tree` and then throwing it away, you can use [`unfoldTreeM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Tree.html#v:unfoldTreeM):

```
f = unfoldTreeM (\b -> (\as -> ((), g b <$> as)) <$> h b)
```

I do not believe there is a corresponding `unfoldTreeM_`, but you could write one (using explicit recursion). To generalize beyond the `Tree`/`[]` connection, you might also like [`refoldM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.3.2/docs/Data-Fix.html#v:refoldM); you can find several similar functions if you search for "hylomorphism" on Hackage.